# Push without Pull

Tags: git

Is there any chance to push some commit(s) without made pull?

One of my team is working away of my office, he cloned our project last week and after he send to us some updates, all of our commits, since last week, were deleted.

When git merge automatically his updates we lost our work

Comment: Try `git reflog <branch>`. Your commits should still be there except that the ref has moved from the previous commit to a new one.

Comment: Thanks, I will try next time

Comment: The literal answer to your question is yes, you can push without pulling. Pull, in Git, just means "fetch, then do a second Git command, usually merge". It's usually *best* to fetch and then do a second Git command (not necessarily *merge*) but it is *possible* to just push, under many varied conditions. But that seems not to be your real goal: you seem perhaps to be confused by Git's merging.

Comment: @torek Thanks, you answered my question